# Dynamics 365 global search and lookup with always wildcard character

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 How to add automatically star (*) when searching in global search or lookup?

Comment: worst case, you can do intercept the RetrieveMultiple plugin & modify the query..

Comment: What did you endup with?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Unfortunately Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, user training is the only way for this wildcard search experience. You should include the distinct columns in Quick find view of the entities for better results.

[Unified Interface Lookup now leverages Quick Find View](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/it/2018/11/02/unified-interface-lookup-now-leverages-quick-find-view/?source=crm)